# Determine if in or near a city

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can one determine if the user is in or near a city. By near I mean within 50 miles.

Is this possible with HTML5 Geo-location, if so, how can I use it so that it works with a switch statement.

Or since it can be within 50 miles, do I have to use a series of if, else if, and else?

For example

```
switch(location){
    case 'San Francisco':
```

and then I could run some js.

I would greatly appreciate any help figuring it out as I don't know how where to begin.

Comment: Geolocate.efem.nearCity("San Francisco");

Comment: @QBM5 can you post an answer with link to documentation?

Comment: @QBM5 It is not working. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/EfCkM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches to get what you want, some more complex than others, i'll give you the simple, or at least the easiest one i can think of (even thought it took me a while to code it :/). You can have an array with locations near San Francisco, and get the name of the city where the user is at the moment, and compare against that array.

```
if("geolocation" in navigator){
    var lat, lon
    var locations = ['richmond', 'berkeley', 'daly city', 'oakland', 'san francisco'];

    $('button').click(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
            lat = pos.coords.latitude; // 37.789709 SF lat
            lon = pos.coords.longitude; // -122.445771 SF lon
            var geoAPI = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lon+'&sensor=true';
            $.getJSON(geoAPI).done(function(res){
                var results = res.results;
                var address = results[2].address_components;
                var city = address[1].long_name.toLowerCase();
                console.log(city);
                if(jQuery.inArray(city, locations) !== -1){
                    alert('You are in San Francisco or nearby');
                }

            });
        });
    });
}
```

I've hardcoded the lat,lon values from San Francisco so you can see it works, just uncomment the real code for production, also note that the Google maps API, returns an array with different levels of precision of the address, so ideally you should loop and confirm for each one, I'll leave that to you. I hope this solves your question or at least helps you out, good luck =)

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EfCkM/3/)

**Edit**: Removed the hard coded coordinates and put them as comments, so the code should work straight away, no need to uncomment, unless you want to test for SF and you are not in there.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! One problem, I am in NYC and it says I am in SF.

Comment: Well the message is hardcoded to work with San Francisco, it depends on your app, if you need to know if a user is whithin a given city or a nearby location, you must add them to the array, in this case "New York", and then change the alert string to say 'You are in' +  city +' or nearby'. More than that i'll get more complex, lets say if it didn't find a match but is whitin the us, you could use math and maybe the same google api to determine if it is whitin a given radious of another city, but that is out of my expertise. GL

Comment: Ah, I see. But since I am in NYC, shouldn't it not alert anything?

Comment: Well if you only want to check if the user is near San Francisco, then yep, it should not alert anything but remember to change the lat and lon values to pos.coords.latitude and pos.coords.longitude respectively so the code can really know where are you at. And if you want you can add an else statement that says "You are not in SF, there are no service in your city" or something like that.

Comment: Sorry to be a hassle, but I did that here: http://jsfiddle.net/EfCkM/5/ and it says I am in or near SF. Not the else. So for some reason the if is evaluating to true.

Comment: lat and lot vars are not changed, look what i meant, is working for me, it says "Not Near SF" http://jsfiddle.net/EfCkM/6/

Comment: oh, okay. thank you. So now, if i am in SF, it should evaluate to true and alert in SF. right?

Comment: Yep, if you are in SF, or any of the locations in the array it should evaluate to true. Try to console.log(results) so you can see what the API is returning, in a different case, you might need to loop over every address in the result and confirm that a given address is in the array, since is not the same for every city. Good luck.